# python - Installing module from Github page

Tags: python, github, python-module

I'm trying to install a web scraper module for Rate your Music (https://github.com/fortes/rateyourmusic), and the following instructions were provided for installation:

```
python setup.py install
```

I copied the contents of setup.py from the repository and ran the above code replacing setup.py with the path to the file. However, I am getting an error stating that there is no module named rymscraper (which is the module that I'm trying to install). How would I download this module? Thanks!

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/dbeley/rymscraper)? Just install it with `pip install git+https://github.com/dbeley/rymscraper`, probably.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It says that it doesnt recognise 'git' as a command

Comment: Install git, like `apt-get install git`? (I thought you have it installed...) Or clone/download that repo locally and `pip install .` from that directory.

Comment: @SUTerliakov i tried installing it using pip install . but it doesn't recognize the path for some reason

Comment: Then add your actions (cli commands at the very least, such that others can read and understand them - and maybe even run) to the question, "i tried, but it fails" does not provide enough information.